# How to Prepare Training data for NLP Bag of words model?

Tags: nlp

I have a Machine Learning Problem: have a set of words: ex, Diameter, Item Number, Phone Number, etc.
When user gives an input Dia, the model should predict the nearest word, Diameter
If user givens an input Part Number, the model should predict: Item Number
How should I prepare training data for this: In this case, are the feature and label the same? Any help? (Bag of words? Hashing)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to train a machine learning algorithm for this problem. **Fuzzy matching** is the way to go. It is based on the **similarity measure** (string distance) of two strings. You can check the distance between input and every word in the vocabulary and select the closest one.

You can also try to train an ML model (not recommended). In case the vocabulary is fixed, you can create the features based on the similarity distance to the vocabulary ([list of string metrics][1]). Otherwise, you can still create features based on letters' count.
The training set can be generated by augmentation of the vocabulary by subsampling part of the correct phrase/flip letters/remove some letters/ add extra letter etc..  ​

​[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metri

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. The reason why I was considering ML was that this goes beyond Fuzzy/lemmatization matching. For example, For an input of "Part number" the prediction should be "Item Number"; For an input of "Product Number" the prediction should be "Item Number" etc. Any guidance?